# Upload Videos in media storage

Tags: magento2, blocks, media, video

I want to be able to upload videos in the media storage and embed them in Blocks. 
Is and how is this possible? I could not find any informations about this.

Comment: use this module https://github.com/davidroberto/magento2-enable-mp4-pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage by your media folder you have to make a folder for video and place there.

and add media path to your static block.

```
<source src="{{media url="video/my-video.mp4"}}" type="video/mp4" />
```

Comment: Thanks!
Where is the default location of the media folder?

Comment: please check in your root folder.

pub >> media >> create your folder